# Refused to load the script as it violates content security policy while working on LWC file

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am a Salesforce developer. I am a beginner in this. So basically I am working on a particular page. This particular page is dependent on one apex class file and two LWC components. The code written in these files have no issues, yet when I deploy them successfully and test them, the page is not loading properly. It's not fetching any records. The strangest thing is same code is available both in higher org and lower org of our development. But when I log in to the portal through higher org, the page is working fine. But when I log in to the portal through lower org, page is not working at all.

So when I try to inspect why is it not working in lower org, it shows, "refused to load the script" as it violates content security policy

Answer (score 3):

When you deployed LWC and Apex to the target orgs, make sure you also deploy any CSP settings your previous orgs have.

> A developer in Salesforce creates a CSP setting as discussed in [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5) help article.

1. From Setup, enter CSP in the Quick Find box, then select CSP Trusted Sites.
   This page displays a list of any CSP Trusted Sites already registered, and provides additional information about each site, including site name and URL.
2. Find Trusted Site.

Make sure your source and target orgs match and have the CSP settings configured.